# Can I access Ubuntu desktop from PuTTY?

Tags: putty

Im u'sing a VPS and I'm using PuTTY to access the terminal, but the terminal is really confusing. Is there a way for me to access the desktop? I searched and tried some suggestions, but none of them worked.

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Comment: Yes you can. What did you do and what error message did you get when connecting ? See https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty- and https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X forwarding from Ubuntu Server Ed to Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298001/x-forwarding-from-ubuntu-server-ed-to-windows-7)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen _(lxsession:9367): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:_
is the error message i got.

Comment: You need to post the command you ran to get that error. If you are trying for forward a graphical application you need to allow X forwarding and an X server on windows such as Xming. Please give more details.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/699789/how-to-x11-forwarding-through-ssh-in-15-10 and http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen _root@ASF:~# lxsession -e LXDE -s Lubuntu_ I am really new to linux, sorry.

Comment: Well, first you should NOT be running graphical applications as root. Second see the links I gave you as well as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo . You should almost certainly NOT be ssh into your server as root.

Comment: Ok, i have been watching tutorials online on how to use the application im trying to host, but everytime i do the same i get a error or something like that, so i thought it would be easier to set it up with a desktop, well. guess not. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to provide more details if you expect help. https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html . As it is now it is completely unclear what and why you are doing these things. In general VPS are for servers and in general you manage servers with ssh (PuTTy) or a web interface such as webmin or cockpit or whatever, there are many options. VPS are not designed to run desktops, although they can.